# Why this happened when I run my react native project?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

When I run the project and look at the localhost only this appears:

[image]

It doesn't really matter if I modify or leave the project blank, the result is always the same when a test form should appear, and the same when I run npm start it doesn't open automatically Metro Bundler, only as it appears in the picture. It's the same when I use the app Expo to view from my mobile, after android bundling complete appears nothing loads, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the code of the project:

App.js

```
//@ts-check

import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';

import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import {Principal} from '../DevMov/Elementos_Components.js';

import React from 'react';

import { Form } from '../DevMov/components/form.js';





const loginForm = {

  usuario: { type: "TEXT"},

  password: { type: "TEXT"}

}



export default function App() {

  return (

    \<View style = {Principal.container} \>

    

      \<Text\>

        TEST COMPONENT\</Text\>

      \<Text \>

        TEST COMPONENT\</Text\>

 

          \<Form model={loginForm}\>\</Form\>

      \<StatusBar style="auto" /\>

    \</View\>

  );

}
```

Form.js

```
//@ts-check

import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { Text, View, TextInput, Button, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

import {Principal} from '../Elementos_Components.js';

// @ts-ignore

import { ModelProperty as ModelProperty } from '../Model/Common_Model.js';



class Form extends Component {

  constructor(props) {

    super(props);

    this.model = props.model;

    this.editObject = props.editObject ?? {};

    this.controls = \[\];

    for (const key in this.model) {

      this.controls.push(constructControlFromModel(key,

        this.model\[key\],

        this.editObject\[key\],

        this.onChangeText));

    }

  }

  onChangeText = (value, prop) =\> {

    this.editObject\[prop\] = value;

    console.table(this.editObject);

  }

  render() {

    return ( 

      \<View\>

        {this.controls.map((control, index) =\> (

          \<View key={Object.keys(this.model)\[index\]}\>

            {control}

          \</View\>

        ))}

      \</View\>

    );

  }

}

/\*\*

 \*  \* @param {String} propName

     \* @param {ModelProperty} prop

     \* @param {any} propName

     \* @param {Function} propName

     \* @returns {any}

     \*/

function constructControlFromModel(propName, prop, value, onChangeText) {

  /\* aca boton de guardado -

        implementer tipo fecha y password\*/



  if (prop.type.toUpperCase() == "TEXT") {

    return (

      \<View\>

        \<Text style={Principal.header2}\>{propName}\</Text\>

        \<TextInput

          style={Principal.input}

          onChangeText={value =\> onChangeText(value, propName)}

          value={value}

          secureTextEntry

        /\>

      \</View\>

    );

  } else {

    return (

      \<View\>

        \<Text\>{propName}\</Text\>

      \</View\>

    );

  }



  function boton(props) {

    const { onPress, text } = props

    return ( 

      \<TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}\>

      \<Text\>{text}\</Text\>

    \</TouchableOpacity\>

    )

  }

}



export { Form };
```

CommonModel.js

```
/\*\*

 \* @typedef {Object} ModelProperty

 \* @property {String} type

 \*/



class ModelProperty{}

export {ModelProperty}
```

I don't know what to do, I'm blank and the internet doesn't have any answers

Comment: Would you be willing to share the project as an expo snack?